# How to find not in values in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here i am having n-number of documents, below are the examples of the documents.

```
{
    "_id" : "ABC",
    "languagesknow" : {
        "lng" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]

    }
},
{
    "_id" : "CDF",
    "languagesknow" : {
        "lng" : [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]

    }
}
```

My question is suppose i will pass input as a one array.suppose in that array i am passing `2 & 5 & 6` means `5 & 6` not there inside `lng`, so want to print the values , how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "languagesknow.lng": { $type: "array" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            languagesknow: {
                $setDifference: [ [ "2", "5", "6" ], "$languagesknow.lng" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: you can put `$match` in front of `$setDifference` to filter out all the documents where `languagesknow.lng` is not an array (using [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator).

EDIT(2): if you want to get single array for entire collection then you need to add [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to gather all the languagesknow into single array and then run `$setDifference` on it, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "languagesknow.lng": { $type: "array" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$languagesknow.lng"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            languagesknow: { $addToSet: "$languagesknow.lng" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            languagesknow: {
                $setDifference: [ [ "2", "5", "6" ], "$languagesknow" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @Prasanna it means that you have some documents where `members.regularStudent` is not an array (which wasn't mentioned in your qustion, modified my answer)

Comment: The thing is that you cannot get just an array, you need to return a JSON document from MongoDB, so do you want this setDifference between input and ALL the documents you have in your array ?

Comment: @Prasanna I did, hope it helps